# Django show posts linked to the spefic user logged in

Tags: python, html, django, session, hyperlink

I have made a blogger website on Django and I would have a page where the user can see/manage their own posts, so they can edit, update and delete.

I have tried to add the page but it keeps throwing an error saying no reverse match?

I am sure how to solve this problem, is something to do with how I have added the author in the Post model to PostAuthor?

[image]
This is my models file

```html
class PostAuthor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter your bio details here.")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["user", "bio"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-by-author', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(PostAuthor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

URLs file

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexPage.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('posts/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='all-posts'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.PostListbyAuthorView.as_view(), name='post-by-author'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Views file

```html
class PostListbyAuthorView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_list_by_author.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['pk']
        target_author = get_object_or_404(PostAuthor, pk=id)
        return Post.objects.filter(author=target_author)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListbyAuthorView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog'] = get_object_or_404(PostAuthor, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context


class IndexPage(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/all_posts.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the user's ID on your link, try this:

```
{% url 'post-by-author' pk=user.id %}
```

Comment: These works thank you. Now I am having a problem where none of my posts are being shown on that page? Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: I just noticed you are using the same URL path for post-detail and post-by-author.  Try changing it, like: 'blog/detail/<int:pk>' and 'blog/author/<int:pk>'

Comment: This did bring the content on the page, this is my html page for authors posts https://gist.github.com/abruno92/de9b3b2f7fcc8c27e407e5eba78933f6

Comment: Oh great =] 
So the page that was loading was actually the detail one...